# Jquery on Hover stop repetition

Tags: jquery, toggle, onmouseover

I am showing div's + text using Hover on Element Div1.
I would like the animation to only show once and not repeatedly everytimewhen the mouse is place on the element again .
Also, is there an other function I can use, instead of Hover to trigger the animation when the div comes into View?

```
$(".div1").hover(function(){
    $(".div2").slideToggle();
    $(".div3").slideUp(300).fadeIn("slow");
    $(".div4").slideUp(300).delay(300).fadeIn("slow");
    $(".divintro").hide();
    $(".divtext1").fadeIn("slow");
    $(".divtext2").fadeIn("slow");
}, function(){});
```

EDIT:
I have decided to go another route and it is working more or less, with

```
if($('#div1').is(':visible')) {
        $(".div2").stop().slideToggle({direction: "up"}, 300).delay(100);
        $(".div3")..delay(200).fadeIn("slow");
        $(".div4")..delay(400).fadeIn("slow");
        $(".divtext1").fadeIn( "slow" );
        $(".divtext2").fadeIn( "slow" );
 }
```

The DIV1 comes into view when visible, but if I navigate away from that div (on the page) and come back to it, the animation starts again but DIV3 and DIV4 are not fading in again, there are visible even before DIV2 Toggle.
Any ideas?

Comment: you are looking for `$(".div1").unbind('hover')`

Comment: @JqueryKing thx, where will I call it?

Comment: Put the line in where you stop the hover

Comment: put and check last line of your hover function

Comment: @wpsupprt `unbind` will disable the handler, is this what you are trying to do?

Comment: @huangism Yes I want to disable the function once it has run, tried unbind  in last line as function(){ $(".div1").unbind('hover');  }); but not working

Comment: @wpsupprt then you should be using https://api.jquery.com/one/

Comment: One is not working...

Answer (score 0):

You can try `stop()` function:

```
$(".div1").stop().hover(function(){ ....
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to work it out with

```
if($('#div1').is(':visible')) {
//alert("is visible");
$(".div2").slideToggle({direction: "up"}, 300).delay(100);
$(".div3").delay(200).fadeIn("slow");
$(".div4").delay(400).fadeIn("slow");
$(".divtext1").fadeIn( "slow" );
$(".divtext2").fadeIn( "slow" );
stopPropagation();
}else{
//alert("not visible");
$(".div2").slideUp('fast'); 
$(".div3").attr("style", "display:none;");
$(".div4").attr("style", "display:none;");
}
```